# ActiveX Control not working in ASP.net but only works using Window Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dll, activex

I have SDK of an Attendance Device ZKS-T7.It has an ActiveX control, while using Window Forms i just drag and drop activeX control from tools menu on Window Form.
But in case of ASP.net i registered this control that has an .ocx file using regsvr32.exe , it registered successfully,then i add reference to my project of its .dll from assemblies menu.
But the problem is when i tried to create its object it gives me an error. 

**WEDS4_CommSV.W4commsvClass aaa = new WEDS4_CommSV.W4commsvClass();**
**The type WEDS4_CommSV.W4commsvClass has no constuctor defined in it.**

This class has no constructor defined in it.
Is there any way so that i can instantiate my class object without using Constructor.
Please check the reference images.
http://tinypic.com/r/se8ua8/9
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=rmo3eb&s=9#.V-i4zyTUfE0

Comment: It sounds like your class is static. Have you tried acting on the class directly rather than creating an instance? Static classes cannot be instantiated and thus cannot have constructors.

Comment: NO, class is not static , its just Public.Check class defination here. [Class defination](http://tinypic.com/r/kf0gia/9)